# Laravel connection database issue because of blocking

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, laravel-api

There is laravel API that connects with Amazon RDS. Usually, all works well, but sometimes API loses connections with the database because of locking it. It occurs at a different time, sometimes once a week, sometimes twice a day. When it occurs, several crons are running and API also processes user requests. I've added SQL logging, but can't find something strange there.(maybe because the SQL queries didn't finish and weren't in logs). Any suggestions on how to catch this issue?

**Laravel 5.4**, **MYSQL 5.7**

Comment: What database management system are you using ?

Comment: `Mysql 5.7`, if you mean that